# How Do I Make Sure An iFrame's Aspect Ratio Is Responsive?

Tags: css, iframe, youtube, responsive, aspect-ratio

I have a very simple question.
How do I make sure an iframe's aspect ratio is responsive?

The iframe is a YouTube Video, and I want the aspect ratio of the iframe to remain 16:9 no matter the browser window size.

Here is my current code for mobile devices:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  iframe, body {
    max-width: 90vw;
    height: auto;
  }
}

iframe {
  border: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 338px;
}
```

Because YouTube iframes do not keep aspect ratio automatically, I need a way to keep the aspect ratio of the video, and the width to be 90vw. The problem with this current code is that, it only adapts the width, leaving unwanted letterboxing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't need media query to achieve this but if you want, you can shift it inside media query. So, how is it being achieved?

Since, we know we need the `aspect ratio of 16:9` and the *width should not exceed **90vw**, thus the height should also not exceed **50.85vw***. And we set the `max-height and max-width` according to your absolute dimension limits that is ***600px and 338 px*** of the container.
Now, setting the `iframe dimensions to the 100% of the container`, it inherits that dimensions. :)

```css
.tv-wrapper {
  max-width:600px;
  max-height:338px;
  width:90vw;
  height:50.85vw;
  margin:0 auto;
}
iframe {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="tv-wrapper">
          <iframe class="sproutvideo-player" src="//videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/489adcb51e1debcdc0/e0d9daac7a1a9b30?
bigPlayButton=false&amp;showControls=false" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the iframe in a container.

```
.media-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; // = 16:9
}

.media-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Wait, I saw the padding aspect-ratio method on w3schools.com, is there any other method to keep an aspect ratio?

Comment: No - the padding method is the way to go for aspect ratio. Also [bootstraps embed class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/#aspect-ratios) is using it.

Comment: I've used the padding method loads, works like a charm, definitely the way to go, but I absolutely could not tell you why haha

Comment: As padding counts towards the object size - this can be used to make the iframe bigger in general (as it is positioned absolute). A percentage value relates to the objects width so this will keep the aspect ratio intact even when resizing the element itself. Its a bit hard to explain by text, but I hope this helps 