# Full width (fixed height) responsive youtube embed banner

Tags: html, css, youtube, embed

I've found the following codepen that resizes/scales an embedded youtube video as a background layer depending on aspect ratio.

https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/PZyMrd

the lines below seem to handle the changing of the video based on the aspect ratio

```
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
```

The resizing/scaling effect works perfectly if I want to have the video set as a background, however, I want the video to scale responsively within a div (not as the background)

Please see the following fiddle to get a sense of what I mean.

https://jsfiddle.net/mhgsre0z/2/

My issue is that I can't get the video to scale (zoom?) based on the aspect ratio as is done in the codepen. Thus resulting in black bars vertical bars on the sides of the video at wider widths

Any help is welcome,

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here is a solution I came up with, there is a slight jump at the breakpoint I tested different values for height/width to try to reduce how drastic the jump is.

https://jsfiddle.net/84jyv3uo/

Comment: I answered this type of question a while back, maybe it would help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47841764/how-do-i-make-sure-an-iframes-aspect-ratio-is-responsive/47843256#47843256 By that method you can make sure even when the aspect-ratio isn't 16:9 you can still make it respective according to the container without hardcording extra padding to make it fit.

Comment: @Highdef appreciate your reply, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for, I am trying to have the video be full width at all times but with a fixed height. I would prefer the video to "zoom in" (or rescale? i don't know what the correct term is) when the width gets wider. I tried to explain it in a screenshot here: https://i.imgur.com/HEVZ1vB.jpg 

Excuse my terrible explanations

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean. The video doesn't play on SO snippets, so here is **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhn01um6/)** link also.

```css
.content {
  max-width: 100% height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-unit {
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

#video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 2px blue;
  border-top: solid 2px blue;
}

#video-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>
    Content above the video banner
  </h1>
  <p>
    I would like to have content above and below an embedded youtube video that rescales/resizes responsively eliminating the black bars at certain aspect ratios by scaling
  </p>
</div>

<div class="header-unit">
  <div id="video-container">
    <iframe class="fillWidth" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W0LHTWG-UmQ?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h1>
    Content below the video banner
  </h1>
  <p>
    I would like to have content above and below an embedded youtube video that rescales/resizes responsively eliminating the black bars at certain aspect ratios by scaling
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, and the scaling works very well, however this is not quite what I meant.

I want the banner to have a max height and the container to not expand to be larger than that fixed height. However, I want the contents of the container to continue to expand but be clipped once the native aspect ratio is greater than the containers height. I will add an image to explain what I mean.



Interestingly enough, the effect works in my first fiddle for the image that is displayed after the youtube video has finished playing.

Comment: I tried to explain a bit better in this screenshot. Notice how when the width is wider, the video effectively "zooms in" maintaining the center of the video, but cutting off the top and bottom. https://i.imgur.com/HEVZ1vB.jpg